# Getting Exactly Equal Predictions from lm and glm in r

Tags: r, glm, lm

I am getting exactly equal results from lm and glm algorithms in r.
Is this possible? I expected similar results but not same.

Please find below my code.

I am working on the Black Friday sales prediction problem and used lm and glm since this was a linear regression problem.

```
#creating the formula for pasting in model statements
a <- paste(colnames(train[,-c(1,2,9)]),collapse = "+")
form <- as.formula(paste("Purchase ~ ",a))

#linear regression model
model <- lm(form, data = train)
result <- predict(model,test)

#glm
model2 <- glm(form, data = train)
result2 <- predict(model2,test)

x <- result2 - result
sum(x)
```

sum(x) = 0.

Please check if my code doing something wrong?
If not, please share your thoughts on this if this possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: Check `?glm` and you will see this defaults to `family = gaussian` with `identity` link function, hence the normal assumption on the error terms producing the same results in both `lm` and `glm`. Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181113/is-there-any-difference-between-lm-and-glm-for-the-gaussian-family-of-glm and https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-linear-model-using-glm-and-a-linear-model-using-lm-in-R

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Can you explain what does " Gaussian family with identity link " means.